# Adding custom handler to Python logging module without a logger instance?

Tags: python, logging

This is a follow-up question to the answer [How to get non-blocking/real-time behavior from Python logging module? (output to PyQt QTextBrowser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349563/how-to-get-non-blocking-real-time-behavior-from-python-logging-module-output-t/14353888#14353888) provided by [X.Jacobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1006989/x-jacobs).

In the Python logging module, the normal method of adding a custom handler is to define a handler class that inherits from `logging.Handler` (we'll call this `CustomLogHandler`). To attach it to `logging` process, we typically do this:

```
import logging

class CustomLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    ... (some code here)...

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(CustomLogHandler)
```

where `addHandler` is a method of the `logger` instance.

**Question**: Suppose we **didn't** want to get a `logger` (i.e. we **don't want** to do the above). Is is possible to attach the `CustomLogHandler` to `logging` itself?

See comments in [How to get non-blocking/real-time behavior from Python logging module? (output to PyQt QTextBrowser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349563/how-to-get-non-blocking-real-time-behavior-from-python-logging-module-output-t/14353888#14353888) for context.

The premise is that it is possible to use custom handlers without any reference to the `logger` instance.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you 'attach the `CustomLogHandler` to `logging` itself'?

Comment: I'm looking to use `logging.error()` instead of `logger.error()`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted (by whomever it is) -- the question is a reasonable one. The answer given is also the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

`logging.getLogger()` returns the root logger instance, there is no further 'up' from that object, and there is nothing *else* to attach a handler *to* beyond the root.

The module-level functions like `logging.error()` use the root logger; quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.error):

> `logging.error(msg[, *args[, **kwargs]])`
>    Logs a message with level ERROR on the root logger. The arguments are interpreted as for debug().

In other words, functions like `logging.error()` simply call `getLogger().error()`.

Attaching your `CustomLogHandler` to the root logger is the correct way to add it to the module.

Comment: I just read in the docs that it is possible to do this: `logging.getlogger('').addHandler(CustomLogHandler)`. That's the answer I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Gilead: You don't have to use a name; it is optional; the empty string is the same as not passing in a name at all.

Comment: Thanks. I figured as much -- I just copied and pasted that from the docs.